# Segfault on fopen c

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, fopen

In the following code I get a seg.fault, I don't know why this happens since I think that I'm passing the correct parameters to `fopen`

Compiling :

```
gcc -o testloadfile testloadfile.c
```

Running attempts :

First attempt

```
./testloadfile "correctme.txt"
```

Second attempt

```
 sudo ./testloadfile correctme.txt
```

In the same folder of `testloadfile.c` I have a `.txt` called `correctme.txt`

The code is the following

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static void load_array(const char* file_name){
  char *read_sentence;
  char buffer[2048];
  char a[100][100];
  int buf_size = 2048;
  FILE *fp;
  int j = 0, c = 0;

  printf("\nLoading data from file...\n");
  printf("%s \n", file_name); //prints correctme.txt  
  fp = fopen(file_name,"r"); //error happens here
  printf("This line won't be printed \n"); 
  if(fp == NULL){
    fprintf(stderr,"main: unable to open the file");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

 read_sentence = malloc((2048+1)*sizeof(char));

 read_sentence = fgets(buffer,buf_size,fp);

  for(int i = 0; i < strlen(read_sentence); i++) {
    a[j][c++] = read_sentence[i];
    if(read_sentence[i] == ' ' || read_sentence[i] == '.' || read_sentence[i] == ',') {
        j++;
        c = 0;
        continue;
    }   
  }

  free(read_sentence);

  for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) 
    printf("%s\n", a[i]);

  fclose(fp);
  printf("\nData loaded\n");
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  if(argc < 2) {
    printf("Usage: ordered_array_main <file_name>\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  load_array(argv[1]);

}
```

This is the mentioned folder [image]

This is the output for `gcc -g testloadfile testloadfile.c`

```
testloadfile: In function `_fini':
(.fini+0x0): multiple definition of `_fini'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o:(.fini+0x0): first defined here
testloadfile: In function `data_start':
(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `__data_start'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
testloadfile: In function `data_start':
(.data+0x8): multiple definition of `__dso_handle'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/crtbegin.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
testloadfile:(.rodata+0x0): multiple definition of `_IO_stdin_used'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o:(.rodata.cst4+0x0): first defined here
testloadfile: In function `_start':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `_start'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o:(.text+0x0): first defined here
testloadfile: In function `_init':
(.init+0x0): multiple definition of `_init'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o:(.init+0x0): first defined here
/tmp/cc0ye2Ms.o: In function `main':
/home/zenoraiser/Scrivania/Università/Secondo Anno/Algoritmi/1718/LAB/Progetto/Esercizio2/testloadfile.c:42: multiple definition of `main'
testloadfile:(.text+0x346): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/crtend.o:(.tm_clone_table+0x0): multiple definition of `__TMC_END__'
testloadfile:(.data+0x10): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: error in testloadfile(.eh_frame); no .eh_frame_hdr table will be created.
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Then i did `ulimit -c unlimited`

After that i run the program with `./testloadfile "correctme.txt"`

In the end I used `gdb ./bynary core`, this is it's output

```
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.11.1-0ubuntu1~16.5) 7.11.1
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
./bynary: No such file or directory.
/home/zenoraiser/Scrivania/Università/Secondo Anno/Algoritmi/1718/LAB/Progetto/Esercizio2/core: No such file or directory.
```

(sorry later i'll try to understand how to use the last command)

Comment: Can't reproduce a crash at the place you state, whether or not the input file exists. However a few lines further down you are overwriting the memory allocation pointer `read_sentence` with `buffer` (or `NULL`) the return value from `fgets`. Later `free(read_sentence);` will fail, because it was not the pointer obtained from `malloc`.

Comment: As an aside: I definitely don't recommend using `sudo` for this!  (1) Don't use `sudo` unless you absolutely have to. (2) Don't use `sudo` on unknown programs that might not work correctly! (Is there any reason you thought you had to use `sudo`?)

Comment: @Steve Summit yes I thought that it may be because I didn't have some permissions for using the file, it was just some random guessing

Comment: @WeatherVane I'll fix that, as for my seg.fault are you saying that you have tried the code on your machine and it works the fopen?

Comment: @SteveSummit question edited, if i double click on correctme.txt it opens with his content (which is a sentence)

Comment: @ZenoRaiser yes it responds correctly to no filename provided, an existing filename, and one that doesn't exist. I didn't run the code further, but noticed the error in my first comment, about trashing the memory pointer returned by `malloc` (your code has since changed: please don't do that in in response to fault reports - the comment trail will not make sense. Am tempted to downvote the question for that reason, but did not).

Comment: @WeatherVane sorry i don't know this mechanics, i'll put it again as before

Comment: have you investigated the core-dump? You cannot rely on the printouts to determine what line causes the crash. Compile with `gcc -g` then do `ulimit -c unlimited` then run program to generate core dump, then `gdb ./binary core`

Comment: Note that because `printf("a")` does not end with a newline and you do not include `fflush(stdout);` after it, you are not guaranteed to see that printed.  Add newlines at the end of diagnostic output — and consider printing it to `stderr` instead of `stdout`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler the original code had `printf("this line won't be printed\n");` with a newline although that may not be guaranteed to flush the output. To Zeno Raiser: see what you caused by changing the question?

Comment: @WeatherVane not changing them it will be a lesson for the next time, later i'll try the suggestions above

Comment: @ZenoRaiser please put `LANG= ` in front of the commands to get error messages etc in English

Comment: @DanielJour thanks that could be my next search on google

Comment: "gcc -g testloadfile testloadfile.c" this command doesn't make a lot of sense. You don't normally compile an executable. You probably want to stick a `-o` flag before `testloadfile`.

Comment: I did it on a user suggestion, which i could have misunderstood @n.m.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual seg fault is likely on this line:

```
 free(read_sentence);
```

It is important to remember that `printf()` sends output to `stdout`, which is buffered. As such, things you send to it will not necessarily get printed if a seg fault occurs.

As for the seg fault itself, let's look at these lines here:

```
read_sentence = malloc((2048+1)*sizeof(char));

read_sentence = fgets(buffer,buf_size,fp);
```

It looks like you think you are allocating `read_sentence` and then putting the data read from `fp` into it (and indeed the code will act like this happened), but this is not true.

Instead, you read the data into `buffer` and then set `read_sentence` to *the address of* `buffer`.

You then do your operations and we come back to the first line I pointed out:

```
free(read_sentence);
```

This is not freeing the memory allocated in your `malloc()` call above, but rather `buffer` which is on the stack, and thus cannot be `free()`-ed. As an additional note, that memory you allocated originally for `read_sentence`, is now leaked and you won't be able to free it.

The best solution to this would be to drop `read_sentence` (along with the `malloc()` and `free()` pair) all together and just do your operations inside `buffer` instead.

Comment: Thanks, i'll try, by "additional note, that memory you allocated originally for read_sentence, is now leaked and you won't be able to free it." this you mean that everytime i tried to run the program there was a memory leak and that now i have some mempry filled but unused  which can't be free-ed because i don't know the addresses of those mempry leaks?

Comment: 30 years ago, that would have been the case, but these days, our OS's can usually clean up a process's leaked memory when it exits. It's just during your program's execution that the memory is leaked.